# Javascript event listener in ReactJS with NextJS causes dynamically imported with no SSR module not to load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

ReactJS and NextJS newbie here would appreciate any advice on below issue! Thanks!

The stack:

- Node v16.6.1
- React v17.0.2
- Next.js v10.0.4

I am implementing a carousel, and--since carousel will need client-side javascript--am using *next/dynamic* to implement a dynamic component with no SSR. This works fine, but when I add a javascript event listener to the dynamic module, the module stops being rendered.

Debugging Next in Chrome DevTools shows no errors or warning when compiling the page. I couldn't find a reference to any additional compile information being available in Next documentation.

Parent module:

```
import react from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'


const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
    () => import('../components/shared/dynamicTestComponent'),
    { ssr: false }
  )

const TestEmbedDynamicComponent: React.FC = () => {

    return (
      <div>
      <div>this is text above dynamic component</div>
        <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR/>
        <div>this is text below dynamic component</div>
        </div>
    )}

export default TestEmbedDynamicComponent
```

Dynamic module:

```
const selectedButton = document.querySelector(".selectMe");
//selectedButton.addEventListener("click", e => {alert("dynamic module loaded!");});

const DynamicTestComponent: React.FC = () => {

    return (
        <div className="">lorem ipsum
        <button className="selectMe">clickMe!</button>
        </div>
        
    )}

export default DynamicTestComponent
```

Result:

[image: result with no listener]

And if I uncomment the line where the listener is added:

[image: result when listener added]

Comment: That's not the React way of doing it. You can simply add an `onClick` handler directly in the button JSX, i.e. `<button className="selectMe" onClick={e => {alert("dynamic module loaded!")}>clickMe!</button>`.

Comment: Even if you do not consider the React way of doing things but just read the dynamic module from top to bottom (which is how JS engine works). The uncommented line will break since `selectedButton`  is `null`, provided that the only element with class "selectMe" is in the `DynamicTestComponent` component.

Comment: I see you use a named dynamic import with ssr: false - in my case i changed that to an import like: import { DynamicComponentWithNoSSR } from ''../components/shared/dynamicTestComponent''; (and comment out or delete dynamic in parent). After that all event listeners started to work. Also for imported elements and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I see you use a named dynamic import with ssr: false - in my case i changed that to an import like: `import { DynamicComponentWithNoSSR } from ''../components/shared/dynamicTestComponent'';` (and comment out or delete dynamic in parent).

After that change all event listeners started to work. Also for imported elements and stuff.